# How do I update my local from Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket for our first few projects and I am unsure of how to get the latest changes from the server. Using team foundation server this would have been easy to do :

[image]

I have a repo on my local and someone has made changes on the main branch and pushed them to the server. How do I sync those changes to my PC? I made some changes last night and they made some changes today and I want to sync the changes they made today to my local version.

When I use the sync button as suggested below it brings me to this and when I click the "Fetch" button nothing happens

[image]

Comment: git pull origin *main-branch name*

Comment: @Cameron637 that does not explain how do it from within visual studio gui

Comment: hit 'sync'? this is a good example of a GUI making GIT far more complicated than it needs to be. Seriously, get on command line, its so much simpler.

Comment: Just because you use the GUI doesn't mean you have to use it for everything. I understand some things are easier on the GUI, especially if you don't know much about git, but often it's a lot easier to just run that one command yourself. I understand this isn't an answer, that's why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: @Cameron637 I was not having a go I apreciate ur suggestion i guess its visual studio dumming me down lol can you see my edit screen shot above plz when i click fetch its not bringing it down

Comment: '@Cameron637 ok so fetch and pull worked but cameron it messed up some refreence which I had to remove but once done it was fine.

Comment: @david sorry I didn't see this until now I am glad you figured it out. You can close the question if you want or leave it up if you want to wait for an answer about how to do it with the GUI it's up to you. Good luck to you!